# Running tomcat by adding external server vs inbuilt maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I want to know the difference in running an application in eclipse by both ways below:

1)Run the application as maven build with 'tomcat' dependency in the pom.xml
2)download tomcat from apache site and add the server, run the tomcat and then run the application as server.

Lets say, my project name is 'messenger'. When I did using first step, i can access with below link"

http://localhost:8080/

but when i did as second step, i can access using below link:

http://localhost:8080/messenger/

can someone, please explain why the difference? arent both the same?

Comment: The way you will access your application inside the server depends on the context it will be using, probably using the maven dependency will deploy your application as the ROOT app/context of your server, on the other hand deploying pointing to a server usually deploys to a different context. you can check the apps on the webapp folder of your server.

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html for your reference